# Monotouch, UIPopover and getting the event

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, uikit, uipopovercontroller

I'm new to Monotouch but I have done some Objective C in my distant past. I'm trying to work out how I would do the following:

1. I have a ViewController with a Naviagtion Bar and button.
2. When I click the button I want a UIPopOver to appear which might have a tableview or button in it.

What I'm trying to work out is how I get the delegate/event from the view I place in the UIPopOver to send it's event back to the calling view.

In Objective C you set the delegate in the calling in the view like this:

```
 UIPopoverController *popover = 
        [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:myPopOverViewcontrol]; 
    popover.delegate = self;
```

So in Monotouch how do you do the same? If set up the UIPopOver like this:

```
UIPopoverController myPopOver = new UIPopoverController(new myPopOverViewControl());
myPopOver.PopoverContentSize = new SizeF(200f, 300f);
myPopOver.PresentFromRect (btnButton.Frame, v, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Up, true);
```

How do you attach the delegate?

thanks

Mike

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can choose from three styles: (a) C# event style, (b) strongly typed/code-completion aware style and (c) dynamic style.

The C# event style is like this:

```
popover.DidDismiss += (sender, args) {
   Console.WriteLine ("Dismissed!");
}
```

If you use the above approach, you must only use C# events on that object, you can not mix and match in the same object.

The strongly typed/code completion aware style is:

```
popover.Delegate = new MyUIPopoverControllerDelegate ();

[...]

class MyUIPopoverControllerDelegate : UIPopoverControllerDelegate {
     public override void DidDismiss (UIPopoverController popoverController);
}
```

And the dynamic style performs no parameter checks, nor will warn you of mistakes, and is very similar to what you would do in Objective-C.   You also need to manually figure out the binding from Objective-C selectors to methods:

```
popover.WeakDelegate = this;

[...]

[Export ("popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:")]
void dismissed (UIPopoverController controller)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Dismissed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In MonoTouch you would probably attach to the `DidDismiss` event:

```
var pop = new UIPopoverController();
pop.DidDismiss += (sender, args) => Console.WriteLine("Popover '{0}' was dismissed", (UIPopoverController)sender);
pop.PresentFromBarButtomItem(...);
```